# What is "mırra", the over-brewed Turkish coffee?

Tags: brewing-process, turkish-coffee

There are many methods mentioned in Coffee SE on Turkish coffee brewing. Are there any other alternatives/variations from the standard way of preparing Turkish coffee? One of such variety I have heard of is the bitter flavored **mırra**.

Answer (score 2):

**Mırra** is a specialty Turkish coffee brewing variety that's known to be very bitter.

The beans are roasted very dark to prepare the bitter possible coffee flavor.

Furthermore, during Turkish brewing process, the grounds are **boiled*** for minutes (and legendarily up to hours) to produce a bitter flavored coffee.

The end result is a very dark and intense beverage which can be consumed in very small amounts in small cups.

Mırra is not very common and mostly can be found in the southeastern part of Turkey and in some nearby Arab countries like Syria or Lebanon.

(*) On the contrary of the standard Turkish brewing method

Comment: how would boiling coffee for hours like that effect the taste?